# Probability of at least one occurrence

Tags: probability

In an electronic game, a character has the possibility, in one of their moves, to summon a blade. For blade A, B and C, there is a 3% chance of activation each. What is the probability of activating at least one?

**Attempt:** I thought of doing it simply: $$\frac{1}{3}\cdot 0.03 \cdot 3=3\%$$

I don't know if my reasoning is correct

Comment: You need to explain more. Does the character select one blade at random to summons?

Comment: Compare your attempt with the similar problem of "*A person has three fair coins.  They flip all three coins.  What is the probability that at least one of the coins lands on heads?*"  Applying the same logic in your attempt to this, does your attempt give you an answer that makes sense?  Remember that probabilities must always be between zero and one (*inclusive*) and may never be larger than one.  What your calculation actually represents is something different.

Comment: @cobre.chapéu Yes, it's the probability of summoning a random blade

Comment: You can make use of the fact that the sum the probability of all events is 1. You can consider the complement of the event your interested, i.e., what's the probability of activating zero blades?

Comment: To be perfectly clear, "*does the character select one blade at random to summon*" you replied "*yes*" but I am not convinced that you understood their question correctly.  Is it possible to summon more than one blade at a time?  Your problem talks about "*activating at least one*" which implies to me that it is possible to activate more than one.  Copper.hat's question probably can be rephrased as "*is it indeed possible to activate more than one?  or do you* **only** *select one blade at random to summon?*"

Comment: @JMoravitz A blade is randomly selected to summon, but I assumed there is a possibility to activate more than one

Comment: The punchline is that $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, that $\Pr(A\cup B) = 1 -\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)$ and that $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$.  The calculation of $3\times \frac{1}{2}$ for the coinflipping question is the correct answer to the wrong problem, that is the answer to the *expected number* of heads to be flipped when flipping three fair coins.  The calculation of $3\times 0.03$ similarly is not the probability of at least one.

Comment: The calculation of $\frac{1}{3}\times 0.03\times 3$ might be correct if we first randomly pick a blade-type and *then* check if we summoned it and don't continue with any others.  It is not correct in the event that each check is always performed e.g. if it is possible to summon more than one.  Assuming you *can* summon more than one and each summoning is independent of the others, you could do this as $0.03 + 0.03 + 0.03 - 0.0009 - 0.0009 - 0.0009 + 0.000027$, or much easier you could do this as $1 - 0.97^3$

Comment: @JMoravitz You can post these explanation as an answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi! Even though you have received an apparently satisfactory answer, it would make it better for future readers if you clarified your problem. For example, if it is the case that the player tries to activate Blade A, and then whether or not they're successful, they also try to activate Blade B, and then again regardless of their success, they also try to activate Blade C, then say so. Then it becomes clear that there are eight possible sets of activation—none, A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, and ABC—and the problem asks you to figure out the probability of the last seven, combined. Is that so?